# Add column description in views in bigquery Terraform

Tags: google-bigquery

I have tables in bigquery which have column description using terraform via their schema.
I'm trying to add description to columns which are created via a view from the previous mentionned tables.

My question, is there a way to inherit the description from the origin table to the view ? or if no, how to add directly column description inside the query that creates the view ?

Cheers,